# Define prop types using flow for stateless functional components in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, eslint, flowtype

I am currently using flow and eslint to cleanup our code base.

Eslint tells you to convert stateless components to stateless functional components. But I haven't found an example for how their props get properly typed for flow. Here is what I tried:

original component:

```
type Props = {onPress : Function}

export default class MyButton extends React.Component <Props> {
  render() {
    ...  // use this.props.onPress
  }
}
```

Version 1 (how I would expect a function to work):
Here flow says `Cannot create MyButton element because a callable signature is missing in props [1] but exists in function type [2].`

```
const MyButton = (onPress: Function) => (
  return(
    ...  // use onPress
  )
}
```

Version 2 (as seen in [here](https://hackernoon.com/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc)):
here eslint complains that `onPress` cant be found. `${onPress}` doesn't work either.
Flow complains: `Missing type annotation for destructuring.`

```
const MyButton = ({onPress: Function}) => (
  return(
    ...  // use onPress (or ${onPress} ??)
  )
}
```

So how do I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your version 2 is close, but you can't define the type inside the destructuring; you have to define the whole object type. It would look like this

```
type Props = {
  onPress: Function
}
const MyButton = ({ onPress }: Props) => (
  return(
    ...
  )
}
```